# Dynamic allocation of memory in Android

Tags: android, c++, memory, memory-management

I dynamically allocate memory in my NDK code, I tried the following two ways:

1)

```
vector<char> buffer_; 
buffer_.resize(len_);
```

2)

```
char* buffer_; 
buffer_ = new char[len_];
```

`len_` is a very big number, in my test it is 132710400, that is around 130 MB.
Both ways works! And when I checked the memory usage in Android Monitor, the memory used only ~30MB. I know the allocated memory is just virtual memory and may not really allocated from physical memory. But I'm sure that I've written and read from this memory, so it should have to actually allocated.
I just want to know how this can happen? Is there something wrong with Android Monitor? Or is there something I don't know about Android OS? Or the Android Monitor can't track the memory used by native code?

Comment: If I remember correctly the memory analyzer in Android Studio only accounts for Java memory, not native.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the command line tools to see how much virtual memory and how much resident memory your process is using.

First, make sure that in your AndroidManifest.xml you have in the application tag `android:debuggable="true"`

Then on the command line, you can execute a shell command using adb.

```
$ adb shell run-as com.yourdomain.yourapp /system/bin/sh -c "ps aux"
```

Fourth column shows virtual size, fifth column shows resident set size.
The reported sizes are in pages, which are probably 4096 bytes each.

If mem use between new and vector are still there, add a `memset(buffer_, 0, len_)` and they should be similar.